# eMMC interface : Parallel vs SDIO

Tags: parallel, sd, nand, nand-flash

I want to use an eMMC card for my application. 
After searching on different websites,I was not able to find any parallel interface supported eMMC chip.

1. Is parallel interface available for eMMC chip?
2. What are main differences of eMMC parallel vs SDIO interface?

I got some additional information from below link.
https://superuser.com/questions/594357/ssd-sd-emmc-raw-nand-what-are-the-differences

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The eMMC [specification](https://www.jedec.org/standards-documents/technology-focus-areas/flash-memory-ssds-ufs-emmc/e-mmc) specifies a data bus width of 1, 4 and 8 bits, with the 4 and 8 optional. The interface does *not* support the slower SPI mode available on SD cards.

The vast majority of eMMC devices have 8 bit capable interfaces.

The power-up default is 1 bit mode, so that the device will be compatible with older controllers.

The physical interface and packaging (at least the pinout) is **defined** by the specification.

The interface protocol is MMC.

[Kingston](https://www.kingston.com/en/embedded), amongst others, sells eMMC devices.